# Jquery sidenav toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

I've got a Side Nav where i wish each list item in the navigation to be clickable, which initiates a toggle of further options for that section.

I've got a fiddle of my rough code thus far to try demonstrate what i'm talking about. The red column would be the toggled section triggered by each link on the first column. However my main issues is the best way to achieve this efficiently. Obviously there are 7 links, which means 7 toggles i would need.

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/visualdecree/Be6ry/31/ *edit - I require the 7 links to all have a separate div that toggles in with different options.

Would i have 7 hidden divs that are toggled by 7 different triggers?

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to get all JS code without yours example?

Comment: @Mat-visual: See my answer with a demo below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery:**

```
$(".sn a").on('click',function(){
    var panID = $("#" + $(this).data('panel') );
    $("div[id*='sn-pan-']").hide({slide:'toggle'}, 1000);
    $(panID).css("left","100px").animate({width:'toggle'}, 500)
})​;
```

**Side Nav HTML:**

```
<ul class="sidenav">
    <li class="sn"><a href="#" data-panel="sn-pan-1">Lorem</a></li>
    <li class="sn"><a href="#" data-panel="sn-pan-2">Ipsum</a></li>
    <li class="sn"><a href="#" data-panel="sn-pan-3">Dolar</a></li>
    <li class="sn"><a href="#" data-panel="sn-pan-4">Sit</a></li>
    <li class="sn"><a href="#" data-panel="sn-pan-5">Amet</a></li>
    <li class="sn"><a href="#" data-panel="sn-pan-6">Et</a></li>
    <li class="sn"><a href="#" data-panel="sn-pan-7">Donut</a></li>
 </ul>
```

**Side Nav Panel HTML:**

```
 <!-- hidden panel that slides out? -->
 <div id="sn-pan-1">
     <ul>
         <li>Stuff 1</li>
         <li>Here</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
 <div id="sn-pan-2">
     <ul>
         <li>Stuff 1</li>
         <li>Here</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  ...
  ...
  <div id="sn-pan-7">
     <ul>
         <li>Stuff 7</li>
         <li>Here</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.sn a {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #
}

div[id*="sn-pan-"]{
    float: left;
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

### [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/4A23Z/)

Comment: Perfect, thank you sir. And sorry to those who answer to begin with, my question was slightly missing some info. But thank to all

Comment: If i wanted to enable it so that if you click the same link, the toggle is reversed instead of started again from the start, how would i do this?

Answer (score 2):

kindly check out this updated fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Be6ry/21/

all you need to do is to look for them using the proper selector, and attach the handler to the click event once.

```
$(".sidenav li a").click(function(){
    alert("you have clicked on "+$(this).text());
});​
```

**clarifying the solution**

1- `$(".sidenav li a")`

this selector will look for all the anchors inside your li list and hold a reference to them.

2- `.click(function(){}`

This will attach a handler to the click event for all the DOM elements that the previous selector has kept a reference to.

3-  `alert("you have clicked on "+$(this).text());`

Just a sample action to do, do here whatever you want.

No need to use 7 different handlers here :)

Comment: Sorry ive updated my question. It's quite possible i'm being VERY dim. I apologize if i am. I see what this is doing, although i cant figure out in my head how i reference a panel per link. So each link having it's own hidden panel with options within. I've updated question as i think it was my poor question that might of been the problem

Comment: Yep. Sorry Mohammed, my question was flawed, apologizes. But +1 for great clarity and solid answer. I was 100% to blame for the missing info required for exactly what i was looking for.